# Use :extend in less with @{param}

Tags: css, less, gruntjs

I made a mixi receive two parameters, which are actually two classes (.class-name)

I tried to extend this class with the & @ {param}. Despite the copilador not give error, the final css not extend the class.

Does anyone have any idea how to do this?

```
.make-icon-button(@extend, @icon){

    &:extend(@{extend});
    &:hover{
        &:extend(@{extend}:hover);
    }

    &:after{
        &:extend(.glyphicon);
        &:extend(@{icon}:before);
    }
}

.btn-pencil-right {
    .make-icon-button('.btn-success', '.glyphicon-pencil');
    .make-animation-slide-to-right();
}
```

Comment: As mentioned by @helderdarocha Less does not support `extend` with intepolation, however I suspect that your goal is achievable with something like `&extend(.btn-success all, .glyphicon-pencil all)`. See [the documentation](http://lesscss.org/features/#extend-feature-extend-quotallquot) for the `all` keyword.

Comment: Hey @seven-phases-max your approach is a good forms to resolve this case. tks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible (as of Less 1.7.0) to match variables with extend. From the documentation:

> Extend is NOT able to match selectors with variables. If selector contains variable, extend will ignore it.

See [Selector Interpolation with Extend](https://github.com/less/less-docs/blob/master/content/features/extend.md#selector-interpolation-with-extend)